# google chrome dev not seeing my security onion SOC, but google chrome regular does?

Tags: google-chrome

I used to be able to access my SOC with chrome developer, but all of a sudden it gives me the “this site cant be reached”. But it comes up just fine in regular google chrome. Thought I would see if anyone else has had this issue?
I uninstalled and reinstalled it, same issue.

[image]

[image]